# How find this maximum of the $|(z-a)^2(z+b)|$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b$ is give postive numbers,let $z\in C$, and such
$$|z|=1$$
Find the maximum
$$u=|(z-a)^2(z+b)|,a,b>0$$

My try: since 
$$z=x+yi,|z|=1\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2=1$$
then we have
$$(|((x-a)+yi)^2((x+b)+yi)|$$
and then it's very ugly,Have someone nice methods? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since $|z|=1,$ then $z$ can be represented in the exponential form as $z= e^{i\theta}.$ Then
$$|(z-a)^2(z+b)|=|(e^{i\theta}-a)^2 (e^{i\theta}+b)|=|e^{i\theta}-a|^2 \cdot |e^{i\theta}+b|.$$
RHS is a function depending only on $\theta.$

Comment: Square it and differentiate it.